# Compactness of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\theta_n(x,t)$ a sequence such that
$$\theta_n\rightarrow\theta\;\;\mbox{in}\;\;C((0,T],H^s)\;\;\mbox{where}\;\;s>1.$$
Consider $\phi \in C^{\infty}$ and
$$g_n(t,\phi)=\langle\theta_n(t),\phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}\theta_n(x,t)\phi(x)dx$$
I can show that $g_n(\cdot,\phi)\in C([0,\tau])$ where $\tau=\frac{T}{2}$ and
$$||\dot{g}_n(\cdot,\phi)||_{L^{1+\delta}[0,\tau]}$$
for $\delta>0$.

My question is: I can conclude that the sequence $g_n(t,\phi)$ is compact in $C([0,\tau])$?

Comment: What is a compact sequence?

Comment: The sequence $g_n(t,\phi)$ admits a subsequence that converges uniformly.

Comment: Any suggestions?